# Laravel ajax select example

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am trying to get qualification of a teacher in select,

**edit.js:**

```
success: function (data) {
    let quals = $('#qual_id');
    $.each(data.qualifs, function(key, value) {
        quals.append("<option value='"+ key +"'>" + value + "</option>");
    });
}
```

**controller:**

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $teacher = DB::table('teachers')->find($id);

    $qualifs = DB::table('qualif_teachers')
        ->join ('qualifs','qualif_teachers.qualif_id','=','qualifs.id')
        ->select('qualifs.qual','qualifs.arb_qual')
        ->where('teacher_id', '=' , $id)
        ->get();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'teacher' => $teacher,
        'qualifs'=>$qualifs,
    ]);
}
```

**view:**

```
<select id="qual_id" class="form-control" style="width: 100px;"></select>
```

**Result:**

> Right now it is showing me [object object] in select.

**Expectation:** it should show qualification for a teacher by default, and it should show all qualifications list in drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how $qualifs collection looks like but you should try using pluck()

```
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'teacher' => $teacher,
        'qualifs'=>$qualifs->pluck('arb_qual', 'qual'),
    ]);
```

Comment: Best way is to return the whole "select" as a view.

Comment: your answer is close to what i want how can i get only 1 and 2 as output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `qualifs` return as `json` instead of `object`.

Convert `object` to `json` by:

```
return response()->json([
    'status' => 'success',
    'teacher' => $teacher,
    'qualifs'=> json_encode($qualifs),
]);
```

Comment: it returned; success, [object object], [{"id:1" "id:2 }]

Comment: how can i get only 1 and 2

Comment: your answer is close to what i want how can i get only 1 and 2 as output?

Comment: You need to convert also the `$teacher` to a `json` also. `json_encode($teacher)`.